# required field validator inside bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, requiredfieldvalidator

this problem drives me crazy .
i have a page i call it from another page into bootstrap modal , there is
a required field validator in the page with some texts and one button if i pressed the button
its postback and drive me to the page and show the field !
i tried to prevent this postback and show the field but i failed .
i tried this too :

```
onClientClick=etc..
```

but nothing happened

i use [this template](https://github.com/onokumus/Bootstrap-Admin-Template)